# What personal information does North Lane have when providing a prepaid card for a Verizon refund?

Tags: united-states, debit-card, gift-card

Verizon sent me a refund in the form of a prepaid MasterCard/Debit card administered by North Lane.  What personal information was provided to North Lane by Verizon to have this card sent?  Is it some token name, address, and account number data set or do they send over the SSN as well?

Comment: Have you tried asking either of these companies?

Comment: @littleadv No, I have not.  Getting through to a live person that actually has that information at either of these companies and explaining the question to them is not a trivial task.

Comment: Explain here then. Why are you asking? What is the problem you're trying to solve?